# Good ways to test antlr performance

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

Is there a good way to compare the grammar between two different files or rules to see which one performs better? As an example, let's say I'm 'starting' with the following grammar that I want to optimize:

```
grammar Calc;
program
    : equations
    ;
equations
    : equation* EOF
    ;

equation
    : expression relop expression
    ;
expression
    : LPAREN expression RPAREN
    | expression (POWER) expression
    | expression (TIMES | DIV) expression
    | expression (PLUS | MINUS) expression
    | (PLUS | MINUS)* atom
    ;

atom
    : number
    | variable
    ;

variable // so the entire variable gets consumed as one token
    : VARIABLE
    ;

number
    : NUMBER
    ;

relop
    : EQ
    | GTE
    | LTE
    | GT
    | LT
    ;

PLUS: '+';
MINUS: '-';
TIMES: '*';
DIV: '/';
POWER: '^';
EQ: '=';
GTE: '>=';
GT: '>';
LTE: '<=';
LT: '<';
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';
NUMBER: DECIMAL ([Ee] [+-]? UNSIGNED_INTEGER)?;
fragment DECIMAL: [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]*)? | '.' [0-9]+;
UNSIGNED_INTEGER: [0-9]+;
VARIABLE: [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
WS: [ \r\n\t] -> skip;
```

And then, perhaps I'm curious whether it performs better if I 'inline' some of the rules:

```
grammar Calc2;
program:    equations;
equations:  equation* EOF;
equation:   expression ('=' | '>' | '>=' | '<' | '<=' ) expression
    ;
expression
    : '(' expression ')'
    | expression '^' expression
    | expression ('*' | '/') expression
    | expression ('+' | '-') expression
    | ('+' | '-')* ATOM
    ;

ATOM
    : ([a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]* // variable
    | [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]*)? | '.' [0-9]+ ([Ee] [+-]? [0-9]+)? // decimal
    );

WS: [ \r\n\t] -> skip;
```

I was thinking perhaps I could generate an output of about a million test expressions or something and then run both of the grammars against it to see the performance difference. Is there a tool to do this or basically to evaluate performance of one set of rules (or file) against another?

Comment: Comparing execution times is an obvious and good measure of performance. But it is a black box approach and doesn't describe problems with a grammar. Details of the parser decisions is the information you also need to have. Look at the Intellij performance information. Intellij only "interprets" grammars, so if your grammar contains actions, you cannot use. [Trperf](https://github.com/kaby76/Domemtech.Trash/tree/main/trperf) is a command-line tool alternative. But it requires a target independent grammar or a CSharp port. Use standard terminology: "unfolding", not "inlining".

Comment: @kaby76 thanks! `trperf` looks amazing. What would be an example of using it: am I able to give it a `.g4` file or do I need to rewrite things? Is there an example of how I would download/convert/use it (sorry I don't know C#).

Comment: If your grammar doesn't have actions (code in java, c#, python, go, ...), then you only need generate a driver, then build it. That's the extent of c# that you use...you don't write a thing. `trgen -s start-rule-name; cd Generated; dotnet build; trperf your-input-file` boom...you got the perf table.

Comment: @kaby76 thanks! But then two follow-up questions -- how do I get the `dotnet` command? And then, 2. how do I download and 'build' your `trgen` app?

Answer (score 0):

Just doing the above made an absolutely extraordinary difference in the parsing time and obviously memory consumption. Here is what I did:

First, I generated a file with 1M equations with the following:

```
x=open('input2.txt','w')
for i in range(0,1000000-1):
    _ = x.write('x=(2+4)*%s-(x*72);\n' % i)
```

Next I timed the two runs with the following:

```
$ # this is the full file
$ antlr4 Calc.g4 && javac Calc*.java
$ time java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig Calc program input2.txt)
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.process(TestRig.java:207)
    at org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.process(TestRig.java:166)
    at org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.main(TestRig.java:119)

real    0m43.721s
user    2m11.130s
sys 0m2.481s
```

After about 40 seconds it runs out of memory. Here is the in-lined version:

```
# this is the in-lined file
$ antlr4 Calc2.g4 && javac Calc2*.java
$ time java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig Calc2 program input2.txt

real    0m7.149s
user    0m12.589s
sys 0m1.240s
```

So the first one where I write the items cleanly takes 43 seconds until it runs out of memory! The second version takes 7 seconds and finishes!

Though it's possible in the first one this is caused by the conditions between:

```
NUMBER: DECIMAL ([Ee] [+-]? UNSIGNED_INTEGER)?;
fragment DECIMAL: [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]*)? | '.' [0-9]+;
UNSIGNED_INTEGER: [0-9]+;
```

Comment: You made quite a few changes between the two examples.  I would suggest that you attempt the changes one at a time to see which changes *really* made a significant difference.  The optimized grammar is going to produce some Context objects that may be a pain to deal with, so make sure each are really improving performance.  For one, I can't see any possible way that using literals like '*' in your parser rule will out-perform Lexer rules (they're just a convenient syntax and ANTLR generates Lexer rules and tokens for you (but autogenerates the Token names.  You'll really want your own names).

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest `program: equation* EOF` and drop the `equations` rule.  (It stood out because you really only want the EOF on a start rule.